# How is wind made

Tags: ocean, wind, waves

Everyone surely enjoys waves in the beach, but one question that has always been hovering around my head was about the wnd.
I have always been told that waves are formed by wind and all, but then where  does the wind come from?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wind is produced by a pressure difference between two places. Air molecules move from higher pressure region to lower pressure region, this movement of air molecules is known as wind.

Comment: Or to finish the idea... wind is caused by pressure differences... pressure differences are significantly caused by temperature variations.  Locally these are caused by the difference in ground cover (water heats and cools slower than land, so that causes coastlines to have fairly continuing breezes) and other variations like clouds and rain, plus the movement of different air masses from other regions.  Globally it's in large part due to the tilt of the Earth and resulting differences in sun angle and day length.  But the take home of what causes wind is the uneven heating of the Earth.